# Better way to get properties from MenuItemDefinition.CustomData

Tags: c#, object, c#-4.0, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using [customData](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/api-docs/html/P_Abp_Application_Navigation_MenuItemDefinition_CustomData.htm) property of the MenuItemDefinition from the ASP.NETBoilerplate Navigation to define some additional properties.

I'm able to access the properties using the following code

```
 var properties = menuItem.CustomData?.GetType().GetProperties();
 bool isMegaMenu = (bool)properties.First(x => x.Name == "MegaMenu").GetValue(menuItem.CustomData);
```

This works fine but is there a better way to access the properties.
I have tried to access the object by casting it to a dynamic first

```
 dynamic t = menuItem.CustomData;
 isMegaMenu = t.MegaMenu;
```

But that produces the following error

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MegaMenu'
```

I have looked at [this post](https://juristr.com/blog/2013/08/object-does-not-contain-definition/) which suggests to use `InternalsVisibleTo` but he uses it on a test case, i'm not sure it's a good idea to use it on production.

EDIT:

Here is what the MenuItemDefinition and the customData property looks like

```
new MenuItemDefinition(
      PageNames.Apps,
      L("Apps"),
      url: "",
      icon: "flaticon-paper-plane",
      customData: new { MegaMenu = true }
)
```

Comment: Show your `CustomData` class.

Comment: @aaron I have added it to the question

Comment: I could not reproduce. Put a breakpoint on `isMegaMenu = t.MegaMenu;` and check the value of `t`.

Comment: it shows that ```t``` has value of ```{MegaMenu = true}``` .

Comment: The first `t`, yes. Check *every* `t`.

Comment: It gives exception on the very first one

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the Dictionary.

In navigation provider:

```
customData: new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "MegaMenu", true }, {"AnotherKey", "AnotherData"} }
```

Then it can be safely consumed in view as

```
var customData = menuItem.CustomData as Dictionary<string, object>;

if (customData != null && customData.TryGetValue("MegaMenu", out var megaMenu) && (bool)megaMenu)
{
  // MegaMenu true HTML
}
```